# Freeing space on iMac by removing CS4?

Tags: uninstall, disk-space, adobe-cs4, imac

I'd like to remove Adobe Master Collection CS4 from my iMac, but I've installed CS5 as well. Will manually deleting CS4 be an effective way to clean things up? I want to avoid leaving junk around, but I don't want to break CS5. Will the CS4 uninstaller break CS5?

**What's the best way to remove CS4?**

Comment: What I would do realistically is to remove both CS4 & CS5 and then re install CS5, more time consuming, but will definitely avoid problems if they happen.

Comment: @Sandeep Not sure why you chose to leave this as a comment, it's a perfectly fine answer and the approach I would take. :)

Comment: I thought it's not a straightforward answer as it doesn't explain to remove the left over files if any...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen a few recommendations for this tool, though it's not free:

http://www.appzapper.com/

And a few recommendations for this one, which is free:

http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/

If you're removing things manually, as long as the CS4 and CS5 files were dropped into different folders in the Applications folder, you can delete the CS4 folder without it affecting CS5.  If you start deleting items from the System and Library folders...you might run into problems there.

Comment: Seen these before, I think.